# Combining 2 databases to create a table with a common column

Tags: mysql

I need to create a table that will combine two database tables together. Both databases have a table that share a common column:  core.

So I need each row to show the common "core".

Do I need to create a separate database to achieve this?

```
Database: hero
Table: cartons_current
+---------+
| date    |
+---------+
| core    |
+---------+
| qty     |
+---------+

Database: hero_label
Table: labels_current
+---------+
| date    |
+---------+
| core    |
+---------+
| qty     |
+---------+
```

Comment: Your example provides two tables that have the same column names. This contradicts what you suggest in your prose. Can you clarify if there is a typo, or what the misunderstanding is if not?

Comment: Yes. There are two different databases & tables with the same column name.  Each table has corresponding columns with different values.  I need both records to show together in one table row.

Comment: And is it that these databases will continue to receive data, or you want to do a one-time merge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT h.*, hl.date, hl.qty FROM hero h, hero_label hl WHERE h.core = hl.core
```

That will show all of the values in the H table as well as values from HL table where they both have an equal core column value. Is this what you are looking for?

EDIT

Sorry i didn't see they were seperate tables. Oversight on my part.

Try this

```
SELECT hero.cartoons_label.*, hero_label.labels_current.date, hero_label.labels_current.qty
FROM hero.cartoons_label, hero_label.labels_current
WHERE hero.cartoons_label.core = hero_label.labels_current.core
```

As long as you have access to both databases and both tables that *SHOULD* work.

Comment: Am I creating a new database to do this or can I do this in one of the existing databases?

Comment: This won't work, because the tables are in different databases.

Comment: @Erik This query will basically take both tables and create one result that combines all the columns from both queries where they have equivalent core column values. If you want to use this as its own table you can create a view out of it. Then when querying it you would just use something like "SELECT * FROM hero_view"

Comment: @NathanielFord added an edit. If both of those databases are MySQL that should work. I don't know if there is an effect if they are different machines. For instance if one is a local DB and the other is pulled from a server. Or if they are on seperate servers.

Comment: @Tony318 That should work, though it is dependent on the databases having the same access parameters. Also, it doesn't solve the issue if he's looking to merge the databases, only if he wants to be able to query them both at the same time. But we need his help and clarification for that. :)

Comment: @NathanielFord i agree. Without knowing the exact reason of why he wants to combine them i think its a bad idea. Thats just an excess of duplicate data that is unnecessary. Without his clarification, i think his best bet may be to create a View out of that query. It gets rid of the complications of duplicate data in another database and will still be able to use it as a table.